# Find a tangent to two quadratic bezier curves

Tags: systems-of-equations, bezier-curve, tangent-line

I have two quadratic bezier curves and I want to find whether they have a common tangent, and if so where it is.

If the first bezier is defined by points $(x_1, y_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$, $(x_3, y_3)$, then the points on the curve have coordinates:

$x = (x_1 - 2x_2 + x_3)t^2 + (2x_2 - 2x_1)t + x_1 \\
y = (y_1 - 2y_2 + y_3)t^2 + (2y_2 - 2y_1)t + y_1$

Or to simplify things:

$x = A_xt^2 + B_xt + C_x \\
y = A_yt^2 + B_yt + C_y$

Likewise, I can get an equation for the second bezier:

$x = D_xs^2 + E_xs + F_x \\
y = D_ys^2 + E_ys + F_y$

The gradient of the tangent, $m$, to the first curve at $t$ is $\dfrac{2A_yt + B_y}{2A_xt + B_x}$,

which must be equal to the tangent to the second curve at $s$, $\dfrac{2D_ys + E_y}{2D_xs + E_x}$.

So $m = \dfrac{2A_yt + B_y}{2A_xt + B_x} = \dfrac{2D_ys + E_y}{2D_xs + E_x}$

Which I rearranged to get:

$t = \dfrac{2(B_yD_x - D_yB_x)s + B_yE_x - B_xE_y}{4(A_xD_y - A_yD_x)s + 2(A_xE_y - A_yE_x)}$

The gradient of the tangent is also equal to the difference in the y-coordinates over the difference in x-coordinates:

$m = \dfrac{D_ys^2 + E_ys + F_y - (A_yt^2 + B_yt + C_y)}{D_xs^2 + E_xs + F_x - (A_xt^2 + B_xt + C_x)}$

But that's as far as I got. The algebra looks too messy from here. Can anyone solve this, or is there a better approach?

Comment: Quadratic Bézier curves are always segments of parabolas. Have you tried “un-parameterizing” them into general Cartesian conic equations?

Comment: @amd I tried (after you mentioned it), but it seems to create a very complex equation. I don't know if it can be simplified.

Comment: If you’re looking for a single closed-form formula of some sort, it’s going to be unavoidably messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single, closed-form solution to this is going to be unavoidably messy. If you take it in steps, however, it’s manageable.

Let $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$ be the control points of the first quadratic Bézier and $Q_1$, $Q_2$, $Q_3$ be the control points of the second, so that we have the parameterizations $B_1:t\mapsto(1-t)^2P_1+2t(1-t)P_2+t^2P_3$ and $B_2:s\mapsto(1-s)^2Q_1+2s(1-s)Q_2+s^2Q_3$, respectively. Quadratic Bézier curves have a nice property: the tangent line at $B_1(t)$ passes through the points $(1-t)P_1+tP_2$ and $(1-t)P_2+tP_3$. So, if there is a common tangent, then there is some value for $s$ and $t$ such that these two points and the points $(1-s)Q_1+sQ_2$ and $(1-s)Q_2+sQ_3$ are colinear. A direct approach from here will give you a quadratic equation in $s$ and $t$ that you can try to solve. Another possible approach is to compute the intersections $R_1$ and $R_2$ of this tangent line to $B_1$ with the lines $\overline{Q_1Q_2}$ and $\overline{Q_2Q_3}$, respectively, and then see if ${\|P_1-Q_1\|\over\|Q_2-Q_1\|}={\|P_2-Q_2\|\over\|Q_3-Q_2\|}$, using signed distances, i.e., see if the two intersection points correspond to the same value of $s$.

Comment: Thanks, I'd not realised those points would be on the tangent and that's very helpful. This looks like a promising approach. It's still pretty messy, but looks slightly easier than my approach.

Comment: OK, I worked through the algebra based on your approach and got a cubic which give the right value(s). Thanks!

Comment: @PeterCollingridge This property holds in general. An $n$th-degree Bézier curve $B^n$ can be constructed from two $(n-1)$-degree Bézier curves $B_1^{n-1}$ and $B_2^{n-1}$ as $B^n[t]=(1-t)B_1^{n-1}[t]+tB_2^{n-1}[t]$. The line through $B_1^{n-1}[t]$ and $B_2^{n-1}[t]$ is tangent to the constructed curve.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an outline of an approach.

Take the point with parameter value $t$ on the first parabola. Let's say the position of this point is $\mathbf{P}(t)$ and the first derivative vector there is $\mathbf{P}'(t)$. Then the tangent line at this point can be described by the parametric equation $\mathbf{L}(u) = \mathbf{P}(t) + u \mathbf{P}'(t)$.

Next, we can eliminate the parameter $s$ from the equation of the second parabola, and get an equation of the form $ax^2 + by^2 +cxy +dx + ey + f = 0$. Or, in matrix form, $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{M}\mathbf{X} = 0$. Actually, **any** conic section curve can be written in this implicit form, not just parabolas. For an easy approach to implicitizing a quadratic curve in Bezier form, see section 17.6 in [these notes](http://cagd.cs.byu.edu/~557/text/ch17.pdf) by Tom Sederberg.

Now let's look at the points where the tangent line intersects this second parabola. This happens for values of $u$ that satisfy $\mathbf{L}(u)^T\mathbf{M}\mathbf{L}(u) = 0$. This is a quadratic equation in $u$. To get tangency to the second parabola, we need this quadratic to have equal roots. Write down the condition for equal roots. This condition will say that some function of $t$ is equal to zero. Solve for $t$.

It might still be pretty messy, but I think that's unavoidable.

Comment: This seems like a good approach. The part I'm stuck with is eliminating the parameter _s_. The implicitization of a bezier seems to give a large function with lots of square roots. A Google search doesn't seem to give any good solutions.

Comment: Implicitizing a quadratic is very easy. I added a link to a document that tells you how. Just a 2x2 determinant. No square roots. Not even any divisions.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: New links: https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/facpub/1/  or  http://hdl.lib.byu.edu/1877/2822